# Disabling specific week days are not working for dynamic array in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting correct result(disabling particular week) when passing the array statically,But not working while passing dynamic array.I am reading on string from PHP and converting that into array and passing to date picker.If have checked the dynamic array is array or not and that values also..It is giving   `if ($.inArray(day, daysArray) != -1)` is -1 always.I have checked `daysArray.length` value also it is 3.

It is working for `daysToDisable` array and not working for `daysArray` array.Both arrays values are same.

Can any body please help me. I did not understand Why It is not working.

```
 $(function () {


      var days="<?php echo $newstr; ?>";
      var daysArray=days.split(' ');alert(daysArray); // not working for this array.Here the out of this array is [2,4,5] same as below array.

        var daysToDisable = [2, 4, 5]; //Working for this value.

        $('#txtDate').datepicker({
            beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
        });

        function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            for (i = 0; i < daysToDisable.length; i++) {
                if ($.inArray(day, daysToDisable) != -1) {
                    return [false];
                }
            }
            return [true];
        }
    })
```

Comment: instead of `<?php echo $newstr; ?>` print the actual data which is echoed. Its always advisable to post the rendered data

Comment: how does $newstr look like?

Comment: $newstr is "2 3 5" I am splitting it with spaces.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think i found the issue

after `var daysArray=days.split(' ');` your daysArray will have array data like `["1","2","3"]` but we need data to be in `[1,2,3]`.

Your final code can look like

```
$(function () {

    var days="<?php echo $newstr; ?>";
    var daysArray=days.split(' ');alert(daysArray); // not working for this array.Here the out of this array is [2,4,5] same as below array.

    for (day in daysArray ) {
        daysArray[day] = parseInt(daysArray[day], 10);
    }

    //var daysToDisable = [2, 4, 5]; //Working for this value.

    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
    });

    function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        for (i = 0; i < daysArray.length; i++) {
            if ($.inArray(day, daysArray) != -1) {
                return [false];
            }
        }
        return [true];
    }
})
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/725u4g9u/)**

Comment: When I am printing my array I am getting output like 1,2,3. same as static array.

Comment: Are you sure the values inside the array are integers?

Comment: What is 'day' in daysArray[day]. I did not understand.And week days values are 0 to 6 only.

Comment: Yes My array values are Integers only.

Comment: Can any body please help me , I struck  here from yesterday.

Comment: running `"2 3 4".split(' ')` will give you `["2","3","4"]` which is an array with strings as datatype.

Comment: Thank ou somuch Cerlin Boss..It working Fine.Thanks alot.

Comment: if this solution helped, consider accepting it as answer

Answer (score 0):

it is happening because on converting the php string, it is generating

`["2", "4", "5"]` not `[2, 4, 5]`

Try this

```
var daysToDisable = <?php echo json_encode(explode(' ',$newstr), JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;
```

instead of

```
  var days="<?php echo $newstr; ?>";
  var daysToDisable=days.split(' ');alert(daysArray);
```